# Get json data structure with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, data-structures, extract

This is a problem that is so hard for me to find using just keywords -- I've scrolled pages after pages and all the hits are on *getting data from json  structure*, instead of *getting data structure from json*.

If you don't know what goal I'm trying to achieve, here are tools to get data structure from json to Go:

- https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/
  This tool instantly converts JSON into a Go type definition
- https://json2struct.mervine.net/
  Convert JSON in to a useful struct.
- https://transform.tools/json-to-go
  online playground to convert JSON to Go Struct

For one specific application, I'm getting data with all kinds of slightly different json data structures, which makes my data extraction failing all the times. I need to compare those data structure-wise, as each individual json data are surely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're struggling to find what you want because vanilla *JavaScript* doesn't have the type concepts you're trying to use.

You probably want to generate a *json schema* or a *typescript interface*, and searching *"JSON to schema npm"* will get you more useful results.

One such example is [`to-json-schema`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-json-schema)

```js
import toJsonSchema from 'to-json-schema';

toJsonSchema({ "foo": "bar", "x": [1, 2] });
/* returns
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "x": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
*/
```

For more specific answers you'd need to provide some minimal sample of input and output, e.g. what would you expect from `{ "foo": "bar", "x": [1, 2] }`

Comment: Bravo! That's exactly what I was looking for, or anything like that would be fine, as my prime goal was to compare the structure-wise differences between all those data with all kinds of slightly different  data structures. You are so fast that I need to wait for 5 more minutes before accepting your answer. thx!!